# HTTPWebRequest with gzip compression

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest, gzip

How can I activate the gzip compression if i get my json data from a webservice?
Here is my code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

How can I set the Accept-Encoding in the HTTP Header?

Comment: `How can I set the Accept-Encoding in the HTTP Header?` `request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "bla bla";` Have you tried this ?

Comment: thanks. that works. can you give me an example how can I decompress the json data to read it, please?

Answer (score 2):

Set the [`AutomaticDecompression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms144087.aspx) property of the request to `GZip`:

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
```

(you can also set it to a combination of `GZip` and `Deflate` if you want to accept both)

---

EDIT: in WinRT, this property is not available. But anyway, in WinRT you should use the [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) class rather than `HttpWebRequest`. The `AutomaticDecompression` property is available on the `HttpClientHandler` class:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip };
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: AutomaticDecompression is not available. I'm coding WinRT App